# proplem using SQLiteConnection in winrt using c#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime

I'm new to WinRT development. I'm trying to use sqlite in c#, however when I try to connect to a local database file like this:

```
string path = @"D:\product.s3db";
string constr = "Data Source=" + path + "; Version=3; PRAGMA temp_store_directory=" + Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path;
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(constr);
```

it returns an exception "Could not open database file", so what is wrong here?

Comment: You've probably missed ":" symbol in filepath. D:\data.mdf

Comment: @Oleg no, that's not it, plus I used it with other location that I took by Copy and Paste from win explorer and it didn't work

Comment: @harryremon Are you sure, is the D:\Data.mdf sqlite db?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't, but I tried with sqlite3 database (product.s3db) it also failed with the same exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think reason is that WinRT applications are sand-boxed and have limited access to the file system. Please try to store database in folder that is available for your application. 
Check the [Windows 8: The Right Way to Read & Write Files in WinRT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432876/Windows-8-The-Right-Way-to-Read-Write-Files-in-Win) article, it may help.

Comment: This should be the answer you're looking for.  Here is an example from some code I have running today that shows one of the possible storage locations that is pointed to by dixeon's link:

`string dbRootPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(dbRootPath, "dbname.sqlite")))`

Comment: Thank you so much, now all I have to do is to make sure I copy the db file to the local folder while deploying ... any idea how to do that ?